Encryption of a small calendar
I'm working on this school project to make an encrypted period tracker for phones.
It's essentially just a list of pairs of numbers (period start, period end). Maybe we'll add some metadata later like comments about each period. Given that it's a minimal amount of data I'm not concerned about file size.
I think I could generate the decryption key from an android lock pattern (those 3x3 grid where you drag your finger around), I understand those have a very limited number of possibilities. From that just invoke a decryption function for a file stored on the user device and keep it in memory until the user is done using the app and then we re-encrypt the file.
The concern for this assignment is that the government could legally require Google / Apple to hand over this data. Whether this concern is justified is outside the scope of the assignment but it is the goal of the assignment.
My limited experience would make me use AES256. Is there a better algorithm I should be using? Additionally is there any obvious flaws with the design?

Usually the lock pattern itself doesn't generate enough information to derive a key from. The lock pattern has usage limits to avoid many retries by an adversary and may unlock keys stored in the phone. Note that in the end you're trying to defeat a system that is not under the user's control; there will always be ways of taking over the entire phone or UI etc.
